# Run member function of the same class in sf::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml

Simple and short: Whats wrong with line 4? I cannot call a void with 0 parameters of the same class.

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game(int width, int height, std::string title) {
    sf::RenderWindow* window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(width, height), title, sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);

    gameThread = new sf::Thread(&Game::run, window);

    window->setActive(false);
    sf::Event event;

    gameThread->launch();
    while (window->pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type = sf::Event::Closed)
            window->close();

        delete &event;
    }
    gameThread->wait();
}


Game::~Game() {
    delete &clock;
    delete &window;
    delete &gameThread;

    clock = nullptr;
    window = nullptr;
    gameThread = nullptr;
}

void Game::run(sf::RenderWindow* window) {
    while (window->isOpen()) {
        window->clear();
        window->display();
    }
}
```

In the documentation of the sf::Thread class everything is explained in examples but not that what I what to do. Visual Studio just says that there is no suitable default constructor available.

Comment: should probably be `sf::Thread(&run, this)` as `run` seems not `static`.

Comment: then is error occurs: `"&": Invalid operation on expression of a bound member function`

Comment: indeed, need qualified name: `sf::Thread(&Game::run, this)`.

Comment: Next one: `Exception thrown at 0x522782A7 (sfml-window-d-2.dll) in SFMLC++ - *.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCDC.` At line 7. When I don't use threading it doesn't occur

Comment: Okay got it. I'm not allowed to make the window global so I have to define and initialise it in the Constructor and pass it to the run function. But `gameThread = new sf::Thread(&Game::run, window);` causes error: `term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`

Comment: You don't initialize `window`...

Comment: And `delete &clock` should be `delete clock` (but even better don't use raw owning pointer, object should do the job, else use smart pointers).

Comment: Of course I initialise window. Code updated

Comment: Drop all this, stop using manual memory management. Store values or `unique_ptr` if you absolutely need this dynamically allocated, run your threaded code in `std::thread` instead and bind variables by lambda closure.

Comment: You create local variable `window`, unrelated to member variable.

Comment: Like I said - I'm not allowed to define a member RenderWindow so I deleted the member and now I use a local variable

Comment: Now, it would be: `sf::Thread(&Game::run, this, window)`.